# Permission denied when invoking Document AI v1beta3 from Cloud SDK Interactive python (abbr. ipython or Ipython)following GCP tutorial for Form_Parser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am following the tutorial at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/docai-form-parser-v3-python#7 I followed all the steps they specified.....

I used Cloud SDK for the development purpose as specified in the tutorial but then

the code they gave is as follows:

```
project_id= 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID' 
location = 'YOUR_PROJECT_LOCATION' # Format is 'us' or 'eu'
processor_id = 'YOUR_PROCESSOR_ID' # Create processor in Cloud Console
file_path = 'form.pdf' # The local file in your current working directory

from google.cloud import documentai_v1beta3 as documentai
from google.cloud import storage

def process_document(
    project_id=project_id, location=location, processor_id=processor_id,  file_path=file_path
):

    # Instantiates a client
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient()

    # The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
    # projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
    # You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/processors/{processor_id}"

    with open(file_path, "rb") as image:
        image_content = image.read()
    
    # Read the file into memory
    document = {"content": image_content, "mime_type": "application/pdf"}

    # Configure the process request
    request = {"name": name, "document": document}

    # Use the Document AI client to process the sample form
    result = client.process_document(request=request)

    document = result.document
    document_text = document.text
    print("Document processing complete.")
    print("Text: {}".format(document_text))
```

Then I am calling the function `process_document()` and the response from GCP I get is this error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
        details = "Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/550698032251/locations/us/processors/640b1155e305c10e' (or it may not exist)."
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1621998239.448000000","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.166.170:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/550698032251/locations/us/processors/640b1155e305c10e' (or it may not exist).","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT_FormParser.py", line 77, in <module>
    process_document_sample(project_id = project_id, location= location, processor_id= processor_id, file_path= file_path)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT_FormParser.py", line 38, in process_document_sample
    result = client.process_document(request=request)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\documentai_v1\services\document_processor_service\client.py", line 440, in process_document
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 285, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 188, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\91982\GCP_CLCBusinessMSGBOT\CLCBusinessMSGBOT\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/550698032251/locations/us/processors/640b1155e305c10e' (or it may not exist).
```

I did set the environment variables as specified & the IAM permissions to my account to access the project is also given with all role of the owner so all the permissions are granted even then the persists

Error message mentiones `documentai.processors.processOnline` - meaning the mentioned permission is not given but I have all the permissions for the particular service account associated with the Document AI Processor as I have owner role

where am I going wrong and How should I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the tutorial and I encounter the same error as yours. The tutorial lacks the step to grant the created service account (**my-docai-sa@your-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com**) with Document AI privileges (Step 5). To do this you can run this command:

```
#Set your project_id by exporting it on a environment variable
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=$(gcloud config get-value core/project)

#Run this command to grand your created service account with Document AI Editor role (read and write)
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT} --member="serviceAccount:my-docai-sa@${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com" --role="roles/documentai.editor"

#Set environment variable to use the credentials from the created service account
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/key.json"
```

You can refer to [Document AI Roles](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-roles) for more information if you want to control your access to the API. After doing all this, you should no longer encounter this error.

You can check if the role was properly assigned to your service account by invoking this command.

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT} --flatten=bindings --filter=bindings.role:roles/documentai.editor
```

It should show the following:

```
---
auditConfigs:
- auditLogConfigs:
  - logType: ADMIN_READ
  - logType: DATA_READ
  service: cloudsql.googleapis.com
bindings:
  members:
  - serviceAccount:my-docai-sa@your-project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/documentai.editor
etag: xxxxxxxx
version: 1
```

Comment: Thank you Ricco D sir for your reply......this solved my issue....now I am getting the result....Thank you once again sir. The policy binding did it.